# How to set shortcut's advanced properties like Font Size (in case of a console app) with PoweShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

**Context**

I know how to create and modify existing shortcuts with PowerShell.
However the `WScript.Shell`'s shortcut objects members seems to be quite limited and for example I could no find out how to set font size for example in case if the shortcut is for a console application?

I am using the following script:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("myshortcut.lnk")
# Setting properties:
$shortcut.WindowStyle = 1
# ... etc
$shortcut.Save()
```

**Question**

How to set font size for the shortcut in case if the shortcut is for a console application?

Comment: The `WScript.Shell` exposes the entire [IShellLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw) interface. I don't know whether .lnk files can store any more information than that. You can research that by looking into the [Shell Link (.LNK) Binary File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943).

Comment: Many thx. It is weird that the public interface supports only the minor parts of the object, the remainig is although documented, but by nature subject to binary breaking changes. Why the developer have to chase bits, and additionally taking the risk of future changes break, when we talking about a *shell* object? It is not a kernel mode TCP driver programming... I am also wondering why anybody could think this is a wrong question.

Comment: @g.pickardou 0 have you found a solution to this? If so, please post!

Comment: Currently I see only the binary read and patch then write back solution. Look for the similar question, how to set the Run as Administrator.